TigerVNC FullScreen command line option not working in Gnome
I'm running ubuntu 24.04 and using tigervnc-viewer which connects to a remote computer. It starts but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't automatically go to fullscreen.
vncviewer -FullScreen 192.168.200.32

I have to manually hit F8 then select FullScreen to force it to full screen.
If I switch my computer over to using XFCE, it works fine. Is there a way to allow vncviewer to go fullscreen in Gnome through the commandline?
